# Facebook group saving

Tags: facebook, facebook-groups

**Question:**

Wondering how I can save a private and public Facebook group just for myself as an offline HTML document forever that I can access freely without logging on to Facebook group?

I essentially want to archive the group so that I can access the data offline anytime without needing to open a browser that requires login. Details of what I want to save include offline access to all hosted files and videos.

**What I’ve tried:**

I’ve saved a private Facebook group as an HTML document through Safari and Google Chrome. If I open this saved HTML document it opens a browser with the link of the web page. The problem is that I first need to login to see this Facebook group. I can’t see the contents, because it can’t save all the data from the web page.

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. You should look at Facebook help to learn if they have a built-in feature that does what you want. If Facebook doesn't include this as a built-in feature, this might require a lengthy explanation or be treated as a software recommendation request, which makes your question not be a good fit for this site. Maybe you should learn how modern webapps work to narrow your question or ask for a software recommendation in [softwarerecs.se].